# How to create lighting for dark objects on sunset background in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lighting

Ok, I have posted to Unity as well but have not received many answers - i am trying to mimic the lighting to an extent that is present in Badlands like here - they have an ambient, sunset like background as if a light were coming from the background, and the objects are nearly black in the foreground:

[image]

I want to be able to increase or decrease the amount that the objects are dark and the sky is bright, exactly like a sunset. I have tried changing ambient lighting, positioning various point and directional lights but I am new to lighting in Unity and this is best I can get

[image]

For me, the backs of my objects have a white tinge and I want to be able like in Badlands to make some of these foreground objects glow with an emission so they are not black. If I do this now they would be muddy.

I don't know where to turn. How can I achieve sunset lighting in Unity? I am using th default skybox here.

Answer (score 1):

I think that to get a more dramatic effect like Badlands you're going to have to reduce the ambient light further and then use some emission on parts of foreground objects that you want to be bright (like the eyes of the Badland creature). Here's a link to Unity's page on emission for their standard shader: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterEmission.html

Alternatively, you might be able to do it by setting both the background and the foreground objects to be 'unlit' and just color the forground objects very dark like you see in badlands. Doing so should also make the game run much faster because it cuts out a lot of lighting calculations. Badlands is only 2d, so I'm pretty certain that all their materials are unlit.